# Exact Target Query Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I'm attempting to execute a query in Exact Target that I was already anticipating experiencing errors with due to a large number of joins as well as querying the same table multiple times, which I have never done before.

The SQL appears sound according to the browser syntax checker I used, however I'm getting an "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'." error when I attempt save this in Exact Target.

If anyone could point out what I'm missing it would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT p.Id AS PrefID, p.rC_Bios__Active__c aS PrefActive, p.name AS PrefName, p.rC_Bios__Category__c AS PrefCat, p.rC_Bios__Subcategory__c AS PrefSubCat, p.LastModifiedBy AS PrefLMB, p.CreatedBy AS PrefCB, c.Id AS ConID, c.SierraRise_All__c AS ConSRA, c.SierraRise_Exclusive__cS AS ConEx

FROM rC_Bios__Preference__c_Salesforce p

JOIN Contact_Salesforce c ON c.Id = p.rC_Bios__Contact__c

JOIN kweos__EOCS_Data__c_Salesforce a ON a.kwac__Contact__c = c.Id

JOIN Campaign_Salesforce camp ON camp.Id = a.kwac__Related_Action__c

JOIN Campaign_Salesforce effort ON effort.Id = camp.Effort_Type__c

JOIN Campaign_Salesforce program ON program.Id = camp.Program__c

WHERE c.SierraRise_Exclusive__cS = TRUE  
AND p.rC_Bios__Subcategory__c = 'SierraRise Exclusive'  
AND p.rC_Bios__Active__c = TRUE 
AND (program.Name = 'SR' OR effort.Name = ('4' OR '9'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T-SQL booleans can be referenced as either `1` or `0` -- if that's how `c.SierraRise_Exclusive__cS` and `p.rC_Bios__Active__c` are defined in your Data Extension.

Also you'll have to use the `IN` syntax in your last `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT 
p.Id AS PrefID
, p.rC_Bios__Active__c aS PrefActive
, p.name AS PrefName
, p.rC_Bios__Category__c AS PrefCat
, p.rC_Bios__Subcategory__c AS PrefSubCat
, p.LastModifiedBy AS PrefLMB
, p.CreatedBy AS PrefCB
, c.Id AS ConID
, c.SierraRise_All__c AS ConSRA
, c.SierraRise_Exclusive__cS AS ConEx
FROM rC_Bios__Preference__c_Salesforce p
JOIN Contact_Salesforce c ON (c.Id = p.rC_Bios__Contact__c)
JOIN kweos__EOCS_Data__c_Salesforce a ON (a.kwac__Contact__c = c.Id)
JOIN Campaign_Salesforce camp ON (camp.Id = a.kwac__Related_Action__c)
JOIN Campaign_Salesforce effort ON (effort.Id = camp.Effort_Type__c)
JOIN Campaign_Salesforce program ON (program.Id = camp.Program__c)
WHERE c.SierraRise_Exclusive__cS = 1
AND p.rC_Bios__Subcategory__c = 'SierraRise Exclusive'  
AND p.rC_Bios__Active__c = 1 
AND (
  program.Name = 'SR' 
  OR effort.Name in ('4','9')
)
```